# How Can I test Junit for S3 Transfer Manger for download file as stream?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have source code as below

```
    try {
      S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder().s3Client( s3AsyncClient).build();
      DownloadRequest<ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse>> downloadRequest = DownloadRequest.builder().getObjectRequest( req -> req.bucket( "bucketName").key( fileName)).responseTransformer( AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes()).build();
      Download<ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse>> download = transferManager.download( downloadRequest);
      return download.completionFuture().get().result().asInputStream().readAllBytes();

    }
    catch( Exception ex) {
        // log.error(Exception occured, ex);
    }
```

I  Need to write Junit for this
transferManager.download( downloadRequest) is giving me null pointer. As Not able to mock it proper. Can you help me to write junit for this block.